# Export Sheets as CSVs overwrites the original filename VBA

Tags: vba, csv

I am saving each sheet as csv and when i save each sheet as csv, it overwrites the the original template filename to the new csv name. It changes from ".xlsm" to ".csv"

How do i avoid that?

My code looks like this:

```
Sub ExportToCSVs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nm As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Control" Then
            ws.Select
            nm = ws.Name
            filenameconvention = "\\Lakesh\ExportToCSVs\" & nm
            ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="\\Lakesh\ExportToCSVs\" & nm & ".csv", _
                 FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        End If
    Next ws
    Sheets("Control").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Csvs Created!"
End Sub
```

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/973578-export-worksheet-csv-using-vba-without-renaming-original-xlsm-file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to copy the worksheet before saving it.
`ActiveSheet.Copy
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="\\Lakesh\ExportToCSVs\" & nm & ".csv", _
                 FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`